# OData JSON Batching returning 200 ok with empty response (ODATA D365 BATCH PATCH CALL)

Tags: rest, odata, microsoft-dynamics, patch

I am trying to update a d365 environment using batch patch calls and I am getting a 200 ok response but no updates are happening within d365. I am using postman to test this out.

Here is the sample call, just to note I also tried running the normal patch call and that worked.

```
Authorization: <authz token>
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = batchresponse_aeadffca-2011-43a1-aa19-282ee1559a14
    Accept: application/json
    Host: localhost:9000
    Content-Length: 1234

    {
      "requests": [
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "atomicityGroup": "g1",
          "url": "https://localhost:9000/users",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "id": "g1-r1",
          "body": {"upn": "u1@domain.com", "givenName": "Jon", "surname": "Doe"}
        },
        {
          "id": "r2",
          "method": "PATCH",
          "url": "https://localhost:9000/users('u2@domain.com')",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "body": {"givenName":"Jonx"}
        },
        {
          "id": "g2-r5",
          "atomicityGroup": "g2",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://localhost:9000/users",
          "headers": {
            "content-yype": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "body": {"upn": "u5@domain.com", "givenName": "Jon", "surname": "Doe"}
        },
        {
          "id": "g2-r6",
          "atomicityGroup": "g2",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://localhost:9000/users",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "body": {"upn": "u6@domain.com", "givenName": "Jon", "surname": "Doe"}
        },
        {
          "id": "r8",
          "method": "get",
          "url": "https://localhost:9000/users",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "dependsOn": ["g1", "g2", "r2"]
        }
      ]
    }
```